# SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended in oracle

Tags: oracle

can anyone help me with this query?

```
select trans_dt,trans_acc_no,trans_desc,trans_amt,transaction_type as trans_type , replace(trans_type,'credit','CR'), replace(trans_type,'debit','DB') from bank_transaction
where (trans_amt>10000 and cust_type != bank_rd_account)
order by(trans_type asc and trans_date desc) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

**remove and between order by clause - it is giving u the syntax error**

```
select
   trans_dt,
   trans_acc_no,
   trans_desc,
   trans_amt,
   transaction_type as trans_type,
   replace(trans_type, 'credit', 'CR'),
   replace(trans_type, 'debit', 'DB') 
from
   bank_transaction 
where
   (
      trans_amt > 10000 
      and cust_type != bank_rd_account
   )
order by
   trans_type asc,
   trans_date desc
```

Please refer the url for more reference about order by

https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/order_by.php

Answer (score 0):

In sql `order` cannot be given inside brackets.it should be given as below

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY column1 ASC|DESC, column2 ASC|DESC
```

Query you required is given below:

```
select
   trans_dt,
   trans_acc_no,
   trans_desc,
   trans_amt,
   transaction_type as trans_type,
   replace(trans_type, 'credit', 'CR'),
   replace(trans_type, 'debit', 'DB') 
from
   bank_transaction 
where
      trans_amt > 10000 
      and cust_type != bank_rd_account
order by
   trans_type asc,
   trans_date desc
```